# How do I scan Firefox on Ubuntu Linux for malicious JavaScripts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, javascript, malware-detection

I run Ubuntu Linux in a VirtualBox VM. I was browsing using Firefox, and I always use Adblock Plus with default configuration (EasyList) and NoScript. Then my VM lagged(mouse badly out of sync with display) and I accidentally enabled JavaScript for an advertisement site. As a general rule of thumb, advertisement sites are infected.

My browser on Linux has no application plugins; in particular - no Java or Adobe Flash.

Several questions:
What's the risk? How do I scan for any potential damage? I have spent a while searching for solutions and answers and there's no forum post or help site that gives a straight up answer.

I know that on Windows, some sites can add malicious scripts and addons to even a Firefox browser. I've actually had to scan for remove some of those from a friend's computer a few times. Does that happen on Linux as well? (In case you're wondering: I have never run Firefox in superuser/unrestricted mode)

Is there a risk of Javascripts being able to download and run "serious" malware or viruses (beyond browser corruption/malicious redirects/unwanted addons) on Linux?

I have looked at antivirus/antimalware options for Linux, and most of them either scan for viruses/rootkits or detect Windows-specific viruses (mail server scanners). Is there any scanner specifically designed to detect malicious browser modifications on Linux?

Does Adblock Plus block JavaScript from third-party sites that are listed in its block configuration by default? For example, if you accidentally disable NoScript for a third-party adsite but it's included in your Adblock Plus blacklist, will the adsite be blocked anyway?

Also, is there any way to clear my entire Firefox profile except for saved logins?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge JavaScript really isn't that dangerous. If you're browser is lagging for whatever reason it's probably due to a hardware or software fault. If the problem were related to JavaScript it would only be because it's poorly implemented (I've crashed browsers many times writing poor JavaScript).

JavaScript can't do any real damage to your computer unless there's a security flaw with your web browser…